# Iterative programming

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, autoregressive-models

I would like to write a code regarding a time iterative variance. The function should look like:

sigma(t)=alpha*x(t-1)+beta*sigma(t-1)

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to bring in this time component e.g. in my for loop. Does anyone have a idea how to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: What is your stop condition? When t=0?

Comment: Please improve the question. There is no R code here. Need a _specific_ example (built with code) and a specific correct result to shoot for. (If you need tutorials in R programming this is not the place.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this??

```
alpha <- 2; beta <- .1
x     <- 1:5
sigma <- numeric(length(x))
sigma[1] <- 1
for (t in 2:length(x)) sigma[t] <- alpha*x[t-1] + beta*sigma[t-1]
sigma
# [1] 1.0000 2.1000 4.2100 6.4210 8.6421
```